# How to push a pojo to activemq and retrieve from it?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I have a `blueprint.xml` in which I am trying to push a pojo into activemq. I want to use that in another route in the pojo format only... but when I'm pushing pojo into the queue, fuse says a warning that is:

```
Cannot determine specific JmsMessage type to use from body class. Will use generic JmsMessage. Body class: com.sia.csl.payment.mpgs.model.vo.CaptureQueueMessageBean. If you want to send a POJO then your class might need to implement java.io.Serializable, or you can force a specific type by setting the jmsMessageType option on the JMS endpoint.
```

My pojo implements `java.io.Serializable`, and fuse is still showing this warning. How would I push a pojo into the queue and retrieve the same from it?

Here are my two `blueprint.xml`s

Blueprint 1, route

```
<from uri="direct-vm:csl-mpgs-payment-1.0-cap"/>
<bean ref="BusinessImpl" method="assembleBeandemo"></bean>
<to uri="activemq:queue:request" />
```

Blueprint 2, route

```
<route id="sampleroute">
    <form uri="activemq:queue:request" />   
    <log message="${body.num}"/>
</route>
```

Here I want to access a bean field `num`. I am unable to do it.

Comment: Share the route you are using

Comment: Its very bad to use POJOs for messaging then you are strongly tied to Java Objects on both client/server side.

Comment: i added the routes u guys can check

Answer (score 0):

Note: I second Claus' note about using Java objects is generally a bad design choice for a number of architectural, practical and long-term support reasons.

Here is how you configure the endpoint:

```
uri="activemq:queue:request?jmsMessageType=Object"
```

[Camel JMS Reference](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)

Comment: i added `uri="activemq:queue:request?jmsMessageType=Object"` but iam getting `java.io.NotSerializableException`

Comment: @SAJINA.JJOHNYA.G, then you need to make your POJOs [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: i made my pojo serializable but now fuse shows error like   `Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.sia.csl.payment.mpgs.model.vo.CaptureQueueMessageBean! This class is not allowed to be serialized. Add package with 'org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES' system property`

Comment: Check that your bundle is importing the package. It is strongly recommended that you consider converting it to XML or JSON to avoid all the Java serialization troubles.